# Как переписать функции fadeIn, fadeOut в нативном javascripte?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть блоки, которые замещают один одного при клике на кнопку без перезагрузки страницы. Код я написал используя `jquery`, но теперь думаю, как его переписать в нативном `js`, чтобы исключить загрузку библиотеки. Особенно интересует как заменить функции fadeIn, fadeOut на равноценные `js`.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#go').click(function() {
    appearance('#start', '#second');
    return false;
  });

  var appearance = function(slide, content) {
    $(slide).hide('fast', showNewContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');

    function showNewContent() {
      $(content).show('normal', hideLoader());
    }

    function hideLoader() {
      $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
  };
});
```

```css
#load {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 11px;
  text-indent: -9999em;
}

#second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start">
  <p><strong>Вы готовы к старту?</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='go' href=''>Поехали!</a></p>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <p>Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации направлений прогрессивного развития. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых заданий требуют от нас анализа системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Разве CCS 3 не позволяет вам воспроизводить эффекты и всякого рода анимацию ? Подозреваю что нет ни какого смысла вообще связывать эффекты с JS, но это не точно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let target = document.getElementById('target');
btn.onclick = function() {
  target.toggleFade('fast');
}

Element.prototype.fadeOut = function(type) {
  let tickSpeed = 1000 / 60;
  let opacitySpeed = 0.02;
  let opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(this).opacity);
  let that = this;
  if (type == 'slow') {
    opacitySpeed = 0.01;
  } else if (type == 'fast') {
    opacitySpeed = 0.03;
  }
  let fadeOutTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (opacity <= 0) {
      clearInterval(fadeOutTimer);
      opacity = 0;
      that.style.opacity = opacity;
      fadeOutTimer = null;
      that.isFade = false;
      return true;
    } else if (fadeOutTimer !== null) {
      that.style.opacity = opacity -= opacitySpeed;
    }
  }, tickSpeed);
}

Element.prototype.fadeIn = function(type) {
  let tickSpeed = 1000 / 60;
  let opacitySpeed = 0.02;
  let opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(this).opacity);
  let that = this;
  if (type == 'slow') {
    opacitySpeed = 0.01;
  } else if (type == 'fast') {
    opacitySpeed = 0.03;
  }
  let fadeInTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (opacity >= 1) {
      clearInterval(fadeInTimer);
      opacity = 1;
      that.style.opacity = opacity;
      fadeInTimer = null;
      that.isFade = true;
      return true;
    } else if (fadeInTimer !== null) {
      that.style.opacity = opacity += opacitySpeed;
    }
  }, tickSpeed);

}
Element.prototype.isFade = true;
Element.prototype.toggleFade = function(type) {
  if (this.isFade) {
    target.fadeOut(type);
  } else {
    target.fadeIn(type);
  }
}
```

```css
#target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
Toggle
</button>
<br><br>
<div id="target">

</div>
```